# SQLAlchemy - how to get all records that are within 1 minute and the same minute of the latest record?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My table has a datetime column that records when the row was updated; call it col_datetime. I need to get the row with the latest datetime in col_datetime and all other records that are within a minute of that record and have the same minute. Example:

```
pk  | first  | col_datetime
1     Dave     2014-03-23 8:23:57
2     Dan      2014-03-23 8:22:59
3     Teresa   2014-03-23 8:23:01 
4     Marge    2013-03-23 8:23:08
```

In my case, I'd need the query to return rows 1 and 3 (even though row 2 is within 1 minute of record #1, it is not the same minute. Likewise, row #4 has the same minute but is a year earlier).

My attempt in mysql only returns row #1 (though I need a solution for SQLAlchemy):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `mytable`
        ORDER BY col_datetime DESC LIMIT 1) as sub 
        WHERE col_datetime >= sub.col_datetime - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
        AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM col_datetime) = EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM sub.col_datetime)
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: It looks like your subquery is returning only 1 result. Whatever you do with that subquery will therefore return, at max, 1 result.

Comment: You also might need to break it down into 2 queries???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sql query will return the correct data:

```
select * from foo;
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | name   | col_date            |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | Bob    | 2014-04-05 19:57:53 |
|  2 | Robert | 2014-04-05 19:58:15 |
|  3 | Fred   | 2014-04-05 19:58:25 |
|  4 | Frank  | 2014-04-05 19:58:48 |
+----+--------+---------------------+

select foo.* 
  from foo,   
  (select convert( DATE_FORMAT(max(col_date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00'), DATETIME) as minute_base from foo) b   
where foo.col_date >= b.minute_base and
      foo.col_date < b.minute_base + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;
```

Sqlalchemy does not support server side functions like DATE_FORMAT or INTERVAL out of the box.  To do it on the server side create custom sql constructs ([SQLAlchemy datetime operations on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540175/sqlalchemy-datetime-operations-on-server-side)).

On the client side with two queries:

```
minute = conn.execute(select([func.max(foo.c.col_date, type=DateTime)])).scalar().replace(second=0)
max_minute = minute + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
conn.execute(select([foo]).\
...:     where(foo.c.col_date >= minute).\
...:     where(foo.c.col_date < max_minute)).fetchall()

[(2, 'Robert', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 5, 19, 58, 15)),
 (3, 'Fred', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 5, 19, 58, 25)),
 (4, 'Frank', datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 5, 19, 58, 48))]
```

PS max_minute may be overkill.